# Modelmetadata additional values always empty MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the below property in my model:

```
    [Required]
    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("Source", "Party.Organization.Caption")]
    public int PartyId { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get the additional metadata value in view as follows:

```
    object s = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["Source"];
```

but it is always returning count 0.

not sure, why, can somebody advise pls?

complete view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<object>
 @using System.Reflection;
 @using r2d2Web.Extensions;
 @using d2Utils.Extensions.d2Type;
 @using d2Utils.Reflection;
 @using System.Collections;

 @{
Type mdlType = Model.First().GetType();
PropertyInfo keyProp = mdlType.GetKeyProperty();
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = mdlType.EditorProps();
Hashtable parties = (Hashtable)ViewData["Parties"];
Hashtable partyroles = (Hashtable)ViewData["Partyroles"];
 }
 <div class="grid">

  <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var prop in props)
            {
            <th>@prop.Name</th>
            }
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var obj in Model)
        {               
        <tr>
            @foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                if (prop.Name == "PartyId")
                {
                 object s = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["Source"];
                 <td>@(obj.GetValForProp<string>(s.ToString()))</td>      
                }
                else if (prop.Name == "PartyRoleTypeId")
                {
                     <td>@partyroles[obj.GetValForProp<int>(prop.Name)]</td>                
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>@(obj.GetValForProp<string>(prop.Name))</td>                
                }
            }
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = obj.GetValForProp<int>(keyProp.Name) }) |
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
 </div>
 <div id="my-dialog"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying field for getting additional metadata. Try to do it like this:

```
@ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.FirstOrDefault(n => n.PropertyName == "PartyId").AdditionalValues["Source"]
```

If you had strongly typed view model with type that contains PartyId better option would be to use

```
 @ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x.PartyId, ViewData).AdditionalValues["Source"]
```

Comment: with the first one, I am getting object reference not set to an instance of exception.null reference exception I am getting.